# Illogical failures of symbolic integration over Boole

Tags: symbolic

Is there a way to work around integration over `Boole` being mysteriously flaky like examples show below? Is there a meaningful explanation for this behaviour?

First, rather obvious integral stays unevaluated:

```
Integrate[Boole[u^2 + v^2 < 1], {u,-1,1}, {v,-1,x}, Assumptions -> -1 < x < 1]

(* Integrate[Boole[u^2 + v^2 < 1], {u,-1,1}, {v,-1,x}, Assumptions -> -1 < x < 1] *)
```

(**EDIT**: This actually behaves much better in v12, although needs `FullSimplify` to reach the result below.)

While the following succeeds to produce a meaningful result:

```
Integrate[Boole[u^2 + v^2 < 1], {u,-1,1}, {v,-1,x}, Assumptions -> -1 < x < 0]

(* Pi + x Sqrt[1 - x^2] - ArcCos[x] *)
```

Why this succeeds particularly puzzles me, when the first one fails:

```
Integrate[Boole[u^2 + v^2 < 1], {u,-1,1}, {v,-1,x},
  Assumptions -> -1 < x < Infinity] // FullSimplify

(* Pi + x Sqrt[1 - x^2] - ArcCos[x]             x <= 0
   Pi                                           x >= 1
   x Sqrt[1 - x^2] + ArcCos[x] + 2 ArcSin[x]    True *)
```

Comment: Whenever integration fails over a domain, I always do something like this: FullSimplify@
  Integrate[Boole[u^2 + v^2 < 1], {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, EulerGamma}] /. 
 EulerGamma -> x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you do one integration at a time :

```
Integrate[Integrate[Boole[u^2 + v^2 < 1], {u, -1, 1}], {v, -1, x}, 
  Assumptions -> -1 < x < 1]
(* 1/2 (\[Pi] + 2 x Sqrt[1 - x^2] + 2 ArcSin[x]) *)
```

Comment: It would also appear that swapping order to `Integrate[Boole[u^2 + v^2 < 1], {v,-1,x}, {u,-1,1}, Assumptions -> -1 < x < 1]` does the trick. Can someone explain why these tricks work?

Comment: This answer doesn't give a perfect solution but... I hope your answer helps people stumbling to these same issues. :)